# Test if point is in convex hull of $n$ points

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

I have $n$ points $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb R^d$, and I would like to check that some other point $y$ lies in their convex hull. How can I do this in some efficient way? I think that there was an algorithm based on checking the signs of pairwise inner products $x_i\cdot y$, however I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 7):

$X = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Then
$$
\text{conv}(X) = 
\left\{
x \mid x = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \, x_i \wedge 
\alpha_i \ge 0 \wedge
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1 
\right\}
$$
The test
$$
y \in \text{conv}(X)
$$ 
can be reformulated as linear program
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^\top \alpha \\
\text{w.r.t.} & A \alpha = y \\
& B \alpha = 1 \\
& \alpha \ge 0 
\end{array}
where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be an arbitrary cost vector, $A = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and
$B = (1, \ldots, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$.

If whatever solution $\alpha$ can be found, then the constraints are fulfilled, which are equivalent to having a feasible set of coefficients $\alpha$ for a convex combination of $y$.

This states that the test for general dimension $d$ is about as hard as solving a linear program of the above kind.

Comment: I hoped that this test should be a bit simpler as solving a (rather general looking) linear program.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11508/deciding-membership-in-a-convex-hull

Comment: Pretty wasteful if most of the points are inside the convex hull. Probably ought to get the convex hull first.

Comment: Just want to mention that if the author of the question was looking for a numerical implementation, there is a MATLAB one [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull).

Comment: @martycohen What would you do if you have the convex hull already?

Comment: @mvw Could you explain why the complexity of finding the coefficient of $y$ is the same as the complexity of solving the linear programming you mentioned? I am thinking about solving the LP you mentioned may need to run over all vertices of the feasible set but checking the existence of the coefficient $\alpha$ of $y$ may just need to find one feasible solution of the LP.

Answer (score 3):

A point $P$ is outside the convex hull from a set $S$ iff the maximum angle $\{\angle aPb|a,b\in S\}$ is less than $\pi$ when read in one direction.