# Best algorithm for convex hull membership problem

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls, decision-problems

Given a point $p \in \Bbb R^d$ and a finite set $S \subset \Bbb R^d$, I would like to determine if $p$ lies in the convex hull of $S$.

A literature search informed me that there are a lot of different decision procedures. Complexity-wise, what is the best known algorithm for this problem?

Comment: How is the set $S$ defined? If it is a finite set, you can formulate this as a linear optimization problem, which can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Yes, it is a finite set! How exactly do you formulate this as a linear optimization problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if point is in convex hull of $n$ points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511112/test-if-point-is-in-convex-hull-of-n-points)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/11508/91764

Comment: So what is the best linear optimization algorithm complexitywise?

Comment: @Luna That question would merit a question of its own.