# Find $x$ such that $x^*Ax=a$ and $\|x\|_2=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

For a given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$, $|a|\leq1$ , assume that $x^*Ax=a$ holds for some unit vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. 
I want to find that $x$.

I couldn't solve it even for unitarily diagonalizable case: $A=U\Sigma U^*$. In that case we end up with two equations:

$$\frac{\sigma_1|y_1|^2}{a}+\frac{\sigma_2|y_2|^2}{a}+\cdots+\frac{\sigma_2|y_2|^2}{a}=1,$$
$$|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2+\cdots+|y_n|^2=1,$$

where $y=U^*x$ and $\sigma_i's$ are singular values of $A$. The two equations are ellipsoid and sphere equations, and there might be more than one $y$ that satisfy them. However, I need only one solution. Any comment on general case would be appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable (equivalently if $A^*A = AA^*$), then $x^*Ax = a$ will have a solution if and only if $a$ lies in the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the eigenvalues of $A$. If you want an algorithm that produces a suitable $x$ given an arbitrary feasible $a$, then something can be done with the help of [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511112/81360) for details.

Comment: If $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable with real eigenvalues (equivalently $A = A^*$), then it suffices to take $x$ to be a convex combination of the eigenvectors associated with the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: You can very quickly see that this is not possible for arbitrary $a$ since the unit sphere is compact so the image of the function $x\mapsto x^*Ax$ is compact.

Comment: The easiest way to see that this is not possible without further assumptions is to notice that it fails miserably for $n=1$. E.g., if $A=17$ and $a=42$, how can you find $x$ such that $x^*17x=42$ and $\|x\|_2=1$?

Comment: OK, you've edited the question – have you tested what happens for $n=1$, $a=42$? I don't know what all those $\sigma_i$ are supposed to be, or what equations they might satisfy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, I think I got your point. Even if we maximize $x^*17x$ over unit vector $x$, we will get 17. $\sigma_i's$ are singular values of $A$